# Javascript help disable column link and tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I disable javascript click and tooltip.

You can see the problem here http://www.vinderhimlen.dk/vind-rejse-deltag-i-konkurrencer-om-rejser

The rating column should not show a tooltip or be a link.

It is attached on my tabels row:

```
<tr class="thumbnail-item" onclick="window.open('<%= vind.tracking %>')" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';" onmouseover="this.style.background='#99ff33';this.style.cursor='pointer'">
```

My tooltip script:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">


  $(document).ready(function () {

 $('.thumbnail-item').mouseenter(function(e) {

  x = e.pageX;
  y = e.pageY;

  $(this).css('z-index','15')
  $(this).css('cursor', 'default')
  $(this).find(".tiptip").css({'top': y,'left': x,'display':'block'});


 }).mousemove(function(e) {

  x = e.pageX;
  y = e.pageY;

  $(this).find(".tiptip").css({'top': y,'left': x});

 }).mouseleave(function() {

  $(this).css('z-index','1')
  $(this).css('background', 'none')
  $(this).css('color', '#000000')
  $(this).find(".tiptip").animate({"opacity": "hide"},100);
 });

});
  </script>
```

Comment: First tell us how do you attach these events. Btw: That rating plugin doesn't work in IE9, I had to open it in FF to see what column are you talking about.

Comment: I have updated my qustion it is attached on my row. Thanks for letting my know that the rating plugin dont works in IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should disable the mouseover event to bubble up.

I have run the following script using firebug to achieve the result.

```
$("#tabel1 tr td:nth-child(2):gt(0)")
.mouseover(
              function(event)
              {
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
              });
```

*edited***__**
As your mouse is over the tooltip, it is not working very good. move your cursor away from tooltip a little bit.

his is where you calculating the mouse points

```
x = e.pageX; 
y = e.pageY;
```

you sould do it like this

```
x = e.pageX+3; 
y = e.pageY+3;
```

in both function of mousemove and mouseover

Comment: It is not bulletproof when I move the courser from the right over the rating column it becomes a link and the hover image is shown.

Comment: I am using Jquery I have updated my qustion with the script. I dont know what you are meaning by moving the tooltip away from the mouse.

Comment: both in .mousemove and .mouseleave?

Comment: I still see my tooltip on hover how do I disable it?

Comment: Yes I have added it. The link is disabled but the tooltip is showing on hover

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy actually. Why don't you just handle the onmouseover/out events in the `<td></td>` tags and leave it out on the rating column?

TR background coloring can be achieved by attaching a pseudo-class to the tr tag or the .thumbnail-item class.

```
tr:hover 
{
    background-color: #99FF33;
}
```

Comment: Because it would be really messy.

Comment: This alone wouldn't be enough, because he's coloring the background of whole row on mouseover. You would color only one cell.

Comment: Then handle the row coloring in the row, and the mouseover/out link/tooltip handles in the cells that are supposed to be handled. And if it gets "messy" why not define a javascript function so you only have to call that. If it works it works, noone's gonna look at the code? Also row coloring can be handled with CSS pseudoclasses